# rails 4: how to collect clickstream data from an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there an easy way to collect click stream data from a rails application?

(for example by activating a gem)

I searched rubygems but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are more likely to find a solution in Javascript, as it is a server side technology. For example, a service like [clickstreamr](http://www.clickstreamr.com/) only requires you to copy/paste some javascript code and it will record your click stream data